# Windows Azure and PCI Compliance

Tags: database, azure, cloud

Probably this question was asked in other threads but maybe something has changed.

Is Windows Azure a PCI-DSS compliant environment?

We are looking for a cloud solution for our system which will store and process CC information and require PCI-DSS compliance.

Thanks
Doron

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/. This is where you will find all information about Windows Azure compliance.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data center infrastructure is PCI-DSS compliant; however, the higher level services of Windows Azure have not been certified for PCI Compliance. The team that handles the data center compliance is the Global Foundation Services.  Here is a PDF that talks about the fact that the data centers are PCI compliant: http://cdn.globalfoundationservices.com/documents/Strategy_Brief_Securing_Cloud_Infrastructure.pdf

As Guarav mentions in his comment, the trust center is the best place to monitor for this.  The compliance specific link is http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/compliance/.

Even if/when the higher level services become PCI Compliant, whatever you build on top of them will still need to go through it's own audit to verify compliance for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by higher level services?

Comment: All the Windows Azure services: Virtual Machines, Cloud Services, Storage, etc. These higher level services (meaning not the raw hardware and data center procedures and policies) are not currently compliant for PCI.